# How can I back up my iPhone without Wi-Fi?

Tags: icloud, iphone

I assume there is something wrong with the battery in my iPhone 4, because it will not stay on unless it's plugged into the charger.

I have about 1,000 pictures on my phone, and when my phone is plugged in, I can look at them, and still use my phone somewhat normally but my phone will not connect to Wi-Fi.

Is there any way I can keep my phones pictures if I have to get a new phone, without doing an iCloud backup?

Comment: Connect to iTunes and backup.

Answer (score 13):

You can back up to iTunes on your Mac or PC desktop or laptop directly over USB.

Connect the device over USB to iTunes, select your device in the toolbar and click Back Up Now.

Comment: Chose "encrypted backup" which will save all your usernames and passwords should you wish to use this backup to restore to your new phone.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer which allows you to do a general backup of your phone which may include your photos, you can also download your photos directly to your computer with software such as Picasa (from Google) or Apple software like Image Capture (in Utilities) or iPhoto (which may also be known as Photos). These methods will also preserve the full resolutions of your photos. Obviously, you will need to have a computer on hand and have your phone plugged into it.

You may also want to check in iPhoto to see if there is a photo stream that already has all of your photos online.

Another option, if you still have cellular data, is to download Google's Photos app (or Google+ if you have an old enough version of that app) and you can choose the option to back up all of your photos, optionally over cellular, but that would use up a lot of data.